# How to implement Waterfall Dialog from within a Dialog depending on the LUIS recognized intent in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I have a Main Dialog in which I am having a Waterfall Dialog of only one step which is to Identify Intent and depending on the intent, I am deciding whether to call another dialog (which is another Waterfall Dialog with 3 steps) or directly reply back the user with response for intents like Greeting and Cancel. Below is the code for my Main Dialog -

```js
const chalk = require('chalk')
const path = require('path');

const {
  ComponentDialog,
  DialogSet,
  DialogTurnStatus,
  WaterfallDialog
} = require('botbuilder-dialogs');
const {
  TopLevelDialog,
  TOP_LEVEL_DIALOG
} = require('./topLevelDialog');
const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '../.env');
require('dotenv').config({
  path: ENV_FILE
});

const {
  LuisRecognizer
} = require('botbuilder-ai');

const MAIN_DIALOG = 'MAIN_DIALOG';
const WATERFALL_DIALOG = 'WATERFALL_DIALOG';
const USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY = 'USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY';

const dispatchRecognizer = new LuisRecognizer({
  applicationId: process.env.LuisAppId,
  endpointKey: process.env.LuisAPIKey,
  endpoint: `https://${process.env.LuisAPIHostName}`
}, {
  includeAllIntents: true,
  includeInstanceData: true
}, true);

class MainDialog extends ComponentDialog {
  constructor(userState) {
    super(MAIN_DIALOG);
    this.userState = userState;
    this.userProfileAccessor = userState.createProperty(USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY);

    this.addDialog(new TopLevelDialog());
    this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
      this.initialStep.bind(this),
    ]));
    this.initialDialogId = WATERFALL_DIALOG;
  }
  async run(turnContext, accessor) {
    const dialogSet = new DialogSet(accessor);
    dialogSet.add(this);
    const dialogContext = await dialogSet.createContext(turnContext);
    const results = await dialogContext.continueDialog();
    if (results.status === DialogTurnStatus.empty) {
      await dialogContext.beginDialog(this.id);
    }
  }
  async initialStep(stepContext) {
    const recognizerResult = await dispatchRecognizer.recognize(stepContext.context);
    const intent = LuisRecognizer.topIntent(recognizerResult);
    console.log(chalk.yellow(intent))
    await this.dispatchToTopIntentAsync(stepContext, intent);
    console.log(chalk.green('after dispatch'))
    return await stepContext.endDialog();
  }
  async dispatchToTopIntentAsync(stepContext, intent) {
    console.log(chalk.blue('in dispatch to top intent'))
    switch (intent) {
      case 'Greeting':
        console.log(chalk.red('greeting'))
        return await this.greeting(stepContext);
      default:
        console.log(`Dispatch unrecognized intent: ${ intent }.`);
        await stepContext.context.sendActivity(`Dispatch unrecognized intent: ${ intent }.`);
        return await stepContext.beginDialog(TOP_LEVEL_DIALOG);
    }
  }

  async greeting(stepContext) {
    return await stepContext.context.sendActivity(`Welcome! how can I help you`);
  }
}
module.exports.MainDialog = MainDialog;
module.exports.MAIN_DIALOG = MAIN_DIALOG;
```

In my case, the TOP_LEVEL_DIALOG is being when I type any query related to that intent, and ask the first step of that waterfall (asks for Name).
**But when I type my name it comes out of that waterfall dialog and shows the greeting response as LUIS is identifying my name as Greeting intent.**

How to solve this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the issue is with your code, but with your LUIS model. If you type in your name and it returns the `Greeting` intent, then you should start by reviewing the utterances in your `Greeting` intent and how your LUIS model is trained/published.

You should navigate to the LUIS.ai site and test your model by entering your name and see what returns.

[image]